# Book trilogy with humans exploring a star system and finding creatures from Irish folklore

Tags: story-identification, books

The story line is about humans exploring a star system, and finding species from Earth's Irish folklore, who had left Earth a long time ago.

Comment: That is very very terse. Could you provide more information on that trilogy? When did you read that? Was it written in English, was it a translation? What did the covers look like? See also [these guidelines on story-identification](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) to increase your chances of having people finding the correct answer!

Comment: Which species in particular?

Comment: With the two pieces of information at hand, there is little to search for sadly. **Any** information would help to add! What was memorable about it? How detailed was the writing? Were it a thick or a thin books? Did you swallow them in a night or were they hard to digest?

Answer (score 6):

It's not a trilogy, there are in fact four books in the series, but Andre Norton's [Moon Magic](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49194-moon-magic) books; *Moon of Three Rings*, *Exiles of the Stars*, *Flight in Yiktor*, and *Dare to Go A-Hunting*, explore the idea that the Fey left Earth when there were too many humans around. Furthermore they have subsequently fled from world to world as the human race has expanded across the starlanes because they don't like to be too close to us for reasons that are discussed but I don't remember.

TheLethalCarrot Has done some excellent googling for me and found some summaries that may help to clarify; the summary for the first book, *Moon of Three Rings* read as follows:

> At the time of the Moon of Three Rings, the galactic trade ship Lydis lands on the planet Yiktor. On Yiktor, Krip Vorlund, a junior crew member, seeks amusement at a beast show. He is strangely attracted to the owner of the show animals, a delicate and mysterious woman, Maelen. When Vorlund is kidnapped by a Combine seeking to control the planet, he learns too well the nature of Maelen's sorcery; she transforms him into a wolfish creature, in which form he retains his own soul.
>
> Between them -- Krip and Maelen -- they spin an eerie tale of dreams and visions, of metamorphoses and extrasensory perception, of timelessness and limitlessness...
>
> Goodreads, Moon of Three Rings

Whilst none of the Goodreads summaries seem to mention Fey, the following review for the fourth book, Dare to Go A-Hunting, does.

> Just started this the other night - we'll see how it goes. Interesting idea to bring the idea of the Fae into space.
>
> So... I realized the reason that the story never seemed clear to me is that it's not. These books are very vague, in terms of plot and description. But I liked this one, despite feeling very unsure of some of the things that happened. I realize this is because the main character is also unsure, but at times, i really want to know more about the characters and the world they inhabit and such, instead of just having hints of what they can do. Still, I think this was a good ending to the series, and it certainly felt stronger than the 2 before it, though I liked Exiles of the Stars because it was a fun mystery.
>
> Goodreads, Dare to Go A-Hunting, Cinnamingirl's Review

This may or may not be what you're looking for, I have the feeling it may be set across a number of systems rather than being set in any single place. Unfortunately I can't remember much else about them, it has been 15-20 years since I last read them.

Comment: I've re-read those books in the past couple of years and I don't remember any reference to the Fey.  Maelen's (sp?) people were secretive, but not afraid of humans or refugees from elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough.  This is not the answer to the question.  Each book is set on a different planet.  (Not in the same star system.)  In this universe there are many races, though humans are very common; it is not a case of humans discovering a new race.  In classic Norton fashion, powers are psycho-technical not magical.

Comment: @DavidW The fact that you don't think this matches, and it sounds like you have good grounds for that opinion, doesn't actually preclude it being the correct answer. Given the slim information given in the OP's question and the fact that quite often people don't remember what was actually _written_ in the book they read. I think those books were about fairies, that's my lingered impression of the story, that may not be right but it may match the OP's case, or not, regardless of that, and it wouldn't be the first time in either case.

Comment: Hey - You may have helped me find a book I checked out of the library at my grandmother's house decades ago, but never got to read. So, even if the OP isn't helped, you can still feel good!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the series called - *Keltiad: Tales Of Aeron* by [Patricia Kennealy-Morrison](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/k/patricia-kennealy-morrison/)

1. [*The Copper Crown* (1984)](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/k/patricia-kennealy-morrison/copper-crown.htm)

   > When lore became legend on ancient Earth and the powers of magic waned, the Kelts and their allies fled the planet for the freedom of distant star realms.
   >
   > But the stars were home to dangerous foes, and millenia later, the worlds of Keltia still maintained uneasy truce with two enemy empires -the Imperium and the Phalanx. Then, at the start of the reign of Aeron, mistress of high magic and queen of all the Kelts, an Earthship made contact with her long-fled children. And while Earth and Keltia reached out to form alliance, the star fleets of the enemy mobilized for final, devastating war....
2. [*The Throne of Scone* (1986)](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/k/patricia-kennealy-morrison/throne-of-scone.htm)

   > Aeron, Queen of the Kelts, has fled to the stars on a desperate mission to find the fabled Thirteen Treasures of King Arthur, hidden from his Keltic descendants for fifteen hundred years. Her search will lead from the depths of space, where worlds are born, to the heart of an ancient enemy's stronghold and on to a trial of courage and magic that even the Queen of the Kelts may not survive!
   >
   > And while Aeron pursues her destiny among the stars, all the forces of Keltia are mobilizing for a war that could set the very worlds ablaze - a war that can only be won if Aeron returns triumphant from her doom-shadowed quest.
3. [*The Silver Branch* (1988)](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/k/patricia-kennealy-morrison/silver-branch.htm)

   > Neither her training as a warrior or as a sorceress-druid prepares young Aeron Aoibhell for her tragic rise to the throne of Keltia or the price she must pay for her first actions as high queen of a spacefaring, magic-using kingdom. Steeped in Celtic myth, this prequel to The Copper Crown and The Throne of Scone depicts the coming to maturity of a woman destined to bring her people into a larger world.